# Restore home-screen auto-rotation after wallpaper change

Tags: samsung, home-screen, wallpaper, auto-rotation

On a pretty new Galaxy S2+, the home screen used to rotate when the device was rotated. After switching the wallpaper of home screen (and perhaps lock screen as well), using the Photo app shipped with the device, the screen no longer rotates. Not even after restoring the original wallpaper, and not after rebooting the device.

To set the wallpaper, I use the corresponding entry in the Settings. I then get a choice of target, whether I want to affect home screen, lock screen or both. When I choose both, I get a choice of Gallery, Live Wallpapers and Backgrounds. When I choose home screen only, then I get the same three but Photos as well. So that's the reason I believe I might have set both. All the item names were translated by me, the actual English versions might be called slightly differently.

How can I restore the factory default of an automatically rotating home screen, without completely resetting the device to factory defaults?

Comment: Does the homescreen auto rotate by default on the s2? It doesn't on the S3 or 4. Are you using a 3rd party launcher? Is it the stock Firmware that came with the device?

Comment: @RossC: It did auto-rotate when I got the device, with stock firmware and no 3rd party launcher. And it's the S2+, not the S2, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry typo on my part. The docs say it doesn't support this. Did you update the device to a newer android version by any chance? Touchwiz doesn't have homescren rotation that I can find on S3 or S4 here. Strange. Can you try this app and see if it helps at all? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate

Comment: @RossC: Sorry for not replying any sooner. I did no android update. Could it be your testing S3 and S4 might have had homescreen rotation up to the first wallpaper change? Installing [Ultimate Rotation COntrol](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.fameit.rotate) doesn't feel good. For once it's only a demo, secondly it looks like it might have to place hooks all over the system to provide its features, and lastly I only want to restore behavior that used to be there, so I shouldn't need an app for that, except perhaps to edit some config. Where are these docs you mentioned?

Comment: Hmm that's odd, sorry when I said doc I had a manual for the S3 somewhere in the office that had no mention but didn't explicitly say that it wasn't an option either. I have no idea, I've never seen homescreen rotation on a stock Touchwiz ROM myself (not to say it isn't there of course). I'll keep digging for now I guess. Would you consider a 3rd party launcher?